# PENTAHO 7.1 - Generating large number of different reports by script

Tags: pentaho

On my Pentaho CE 7.1 I often need to generate large number of reports (`*.prpt`) with different attributes.

For example, I have a report that shows data for a day, and I need to generate those reports for each day since September 2017.

Is there any way how create a script, that would execute those `*.prpt` files one by one for each day since September 2017 until now?

I have been checking API on official Pentaho documentation, but it does not seem to be such option there. Perhaps some kind of hack, like sending parameters in URL or so?

Comment: Retroactively? With the platform, not that I know. But with the PDI it is very easy.

Comment: @AlainD could you please explain further?

Answer (score 0):

Create your *.prpt with the Report Designer and use a parameter to select one day in your data.

Then open PDI, with first step to generate a date starting from 2017-09-10, and give this date to a `Pentaho Reporting Example` step. Then do what you need with the report output (mail, save them in the Pentaho-solutions,...).

You have a use case very similar in the sample directory which is shipped with the Pentaho Data Integrator. It is named `Pentaho Reporting Output Example.ktr`.